# C++20 Compile Time Evaluation, Optimization and Smartpointers

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, inlining

Using `std::shared_ptr` does not allow for compile time evaluation, constexpr, inlining and other optimizations. This is probably due to multithreading safety.

So I experimented with my own simple smart-pointer, just to see what is possible if thread safety is not needed. This is just a minimal draft of an intrusive, linked list reference tracking smart pointer (see the comments in the example for more info).

Questions:

1. The example below compiles to full compile time evaluation on clang. On gcc it does not. Why?
2. clang does compile time evaluate everything, if, and only if some null pointer checks are included (see `~myptr()`). Why?
3. These null pointer checks are not actually needed, due to the invariant of the smart pointer. Is there an attribute etc. that tells clang to trust the pointer is never null?

https://godbolt.org/z/1xK1r4YjT

```
#include <memory>
//#include <iostream>

// Simplistic linked list reference tracking smart pointer.
//
// Linking instead of reference counting is interesting because it allows for extra functionality such as
// moving around referenced memory blocks (growable objects, defragmentation), "set null" 
// semantics on delete, etc.
// 
// Not thread safe, but (trying to) support a high level of compile time evaluation, inlining, 
// optimization. 
template<typename T>
struct myptr {
private:
    T * p;
    myptr * next;
public:
    constexpr myptr(T * p) noexcept : p(p), next(p ? p->first : nullptr) {
        p->first = this;
    }
    constexpr myptr(const myptr & other) noexcept : myptr(other.p) {}

    constexpr T &operator*() {
        return *p;
    }
    constexpr T *operator->() {
        return p;
    }
    T &operator=(const myptr & other) = delete;
    T &operator=(const myptr && other) = delete;

    constexpr ~myptr() noexcept {
        if (p) {
            // We must remove `this` from the list. As these are typically stack references, they will be 
            // mostly LIFO, so we will typically find it immediately.
#if 1
            myptr ** pnext = &(p->first);
            while (*pnext) { 
                if (*pnext == this) {
                    // Found our smart pointer, bypass.
                    *pnext = next;
                    break;
                }
                pnext = &((*pnext)->next);
            }
#else
            // NOTE: the loop with null check (above) should not be necessary, as the invariant of myptr holds 
            // that we will always find `this` in the list and never hit a null pointer. 
            // However, if we use the code below, clang will immediately stop compile time evaluation. 
            // Is there some "function with potential null pointer fault" restriction in play?
            myptr ** pnext = &(p->first);
            while (*pnext != this) { 
                pnext = &((*pnext)->next);
            }
            // Bypass.
            *pnext = next;
#endif
            next = nullptr;
            if (!p->first) {
                // The last reference vanished.
                delete p;
            }
            p = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

struct Obj {
    int i{20};
    inline ~Obj() noexcept {
        i = -1;
        //std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    // intrusive linked references list
    struct myptr<Obj> * first{};
    friend struct myptr<Obj>;
};

// Try different pointers:
using obj_ptr = myptr<Obj>;
//using obj_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Obj>;
//using obj_ptr = Obj*;

//constexpr
inline 
int fun(obj_ptr obj) {
    return obj->i;
}

int main() {
    obj_ptr obj(new Obj);
    {   obj_ptr obj2(obj);
        obj2->i += 1;
    }
    obj_ptr obj3(obj);
    obj3->i *= 2;
    return fun(obj);
}
```

Comment: "*compile time evaluation, constexpr*" These are more or less the same thing. "*inlining and other optimizations*" What precisely cannot be inlined? And what "other optimizations" are you talking about?

Comment: I think it is unsurprising that clang and gcc gives different results. I imagine these constexpr evaluations are still in development.

Comment: the compiler is under no obligation to evaluate your code at compile time, there will be certain operations allowed in `constexpr` by the standard that the compiler is unable to evaluate at compile time

Comment: @NicolBolas, please have a look at the linked godbolt.org, you can see the result in the assembly output. Generally speaking, I would like for the smart pointer to have no runtime overhead, whenever possible, i.e. when the referencing is predictable.

Comment: @markus: That's not what `constexpr` means. You can't run a `constexpr` function at compile time on data that isn't a constant expression. Also, what "predictable" means will vary from compiler to compiler, so there's never going to be a guarantee of anything with this code. You can increase or decrease the likelihood of some optimizations, but it will always vary from compiler to compiler (and even among versions of the same compiler).

Comment: @NicolBolas, like I said in the question, `constexpr` is only one aspect, it's also about inlining, constant expression evaluation, copy/move elision, and all the other possible compiler optimizations. It's not about a _guarantee_ of optimization, it's about _admissibility_, and a _good chance_ of optimization. Btw. technically I disagree: `constexpr` just states that the data must be _LiteralType_, no need to be constant, as you can clearly see in the `constexpr` constructor/destructor of `myptr` manipulating intrusive data via `p`.

Comment: @markus: The "data" I was speaking of was `obj`. That variable is not declared `constexpr`, so it is not a constant expression. "*it's about admissibility, and a good chance of optimization*" I don't know what you mean by "admissibility", but so long as the compiler can see all of the code involved, *any* equivalently-behaving optimization is possible. And "good chance" will vary even among versions of a compiler.

Comment: @AlanBirtles that's saying that the compiler is under no obligation to be a standards-conforming compiler.  Claiming that it is following the standard _is_ an obligation.  The `constexpr` is not optional, but well-defined as to what is allowed and should give the same results (of being a compile-time constant) on any compiler.

Comment: @JDługosz no, `constexpr` [states that it is possible to evaluate the code at compile time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) not that the compiler has to evaluate it at compile time, the compiler should accept what the standard says is allowed and might reject what the standard says is not allowed but it is up to the compiler whether it actually evaluates it at compile time

Comment: E.g. clang and gcc are (fairly) standards conformant but choose not to evaluate `constexpr` when optimisations are disabled: https://godbolt.org/z/1r941avKb

Comment: @AlanBirtles  you're saying that given `constexpr size_t S = ...;` then `int A[S];` may or may not be legal depending on the compiler?  Or that the order of initialization of globals may still be an issue on some compilers because it chose not to respect the `constexpr` specifier?  That would make any use of it non-portable.

Comment: no, that is requried to work by the standard. But if a constexpr expression is used somewhere constexpr is not required (as is the case in this question) then the compiler doesn't have to evaluate at compile time

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe you are right! I extended the example to cover more smart pointer use cases and now only clang can compile it, the others (gcc, msvc) both crash. 
https://godbolt.org/z/c95scY9bc
I don't see how the code is not conformant to C++20.

Answer (score 0):

> The example below compiles to full compile time evaluation on clang. On gcc it does not. Why?

Because neither behavior is required. `constexpr` doesn't mean "function will execute at compile-time". It means that the compiler *may* do such evaluation at compile-time. It is only required if the function is called in a context that *must* evaluate to a constant expression.

And that's not what you're doing here.

The optimization you're seeing on Clang has nothing to do with `constexpr` qualifiers. Take those qualifiers away, and [Clang still optimizes it away](https://godbolt.org/z/s5Ezh81qf). They're just regular compiler optimizations.

> clang does compile time evaluate everything, if, and only if some null pointer checks are included (see ~myptr()). Why?

Compiler optimizations are picky and sometimes very arbitrary.

Comment: Like I tried to explain, `constexpr` is but one aspect, albeit an important one. It means that I can use this smart pointer in calculations that lead to a constant expression. I cannot do that with `std::shared_ptr`. To prove my point I forced it, now gcc can do it too:
https://godbolt.org/z/18qMq9zeq

Comment: And when I asked about optimization, I was asking about what common compilers _can_ do today (and the _why_) and not about what the standard _mandates_. 
I am assuming that what compilers can optimize today, they will do so in the future. It's a competition too, so other compilers will follow. So designing a smart pointer in a way that _can_ be optimized today, seems like a valid strategy for good performance to me. Right?